# How can I print a HTML5 video in black and white?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video (live webcam) to which I apply a CSS class in order to turn the video black and white:

```
.grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
  filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

On the screen it works just fine.

Now, there is also a print button with a simple **window.print();** function. After clicking, the print preview opens and shows the video in color again.

Is it somehow possible to print the grayscale version of the video?

Comment: You could draw the video to canvas and greyscale the image, and print that instead of the actual video element.

Comment: Have you set your media type to print? `@media print { }`

Comment: @Ian: If it's not already in a `@media screen { }` or similar, it would apply to all media (including print), right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm - that's quite possibly true actually

Comment: @Ian, yeah its set both in the screen and print.css. ndugger, thanks I will try that